# Says it can't find the txt file

Tags: python-3.x

This is the code that I have. I'm just trying to get it to read and show what's in the file. Whenever I run it, it says that the file/directory can't be found? But my python and text files are in the same file.. 
I'm new to this so I'm not sure where I'm going wrong with it.

```
def main():
    f = open("rules.txt", "r")
    if f.mode == "r":
        contents = f.read()
        print(contents)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: `But my python and text files are in the same file` <- do you mean to say that your text file and the file containing the above python code are in the same directory?

Comment: It doesn't matter where your python file is stored. What matters is what directory you're in when you're running it.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry if this is a stupid question.. but how do I know if they're in the same directory and how do I get them into the same directory..?

Comment: What do you mean by "they"?

Comment: The files and the program.